# Какой аналог питоновского replace() в с++

Tags: c++

Какой аналог питоновского replace() в с++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тоже replace(). Основные понятия во многих языках схожи.

Answer (score 2):

Не поверите - `replace()`

```
string s1 = "abcdef";
string s2 = "1234567890";

s2.replace(2, 4, s1); // s2 = "12abcdef7890"
s2 = "1234567890";
s2.replace(3, 2, s1); // s2 = "123abcdef67890"
s2 = "1234567890";
s2.replace(5, 1, s1); // s2 = "12345abcdef7890"

// замена символов, функция replace()
string s1 = "abcdef";
string s2 = "1234567890";

s2.replace(2, 4, s1); // s2 = "12abcdef7890"
s2 = "1234567890";
s2.replace(3, 2, s1); // s2 = "123abcdef67890"

s2 = "1234567890";
s2.replace(5, 1, s1); // s2 = "12345abcdef7890"
s2 = "1234567890";
s2.replace(5, 1, s1, 2, 3); // s2 = "12345cde7890"
s2 = "1234567890";
s2.replace(4, 2, s1, 0, 4); // s2 = "1234abcd7890"
```

Answer (score 1):

Такого replace, как в питоне, то есть заменить "some_text" на "some_another_text" в строке "hello some_text", в с++ нет. Но есть 2 функции, с помощью которых можно сделать это: replace (заменяет определённое количество символов с определённой позиции на строку) и find (ищет подстроку в строке):

```cpp
string sourceString = "Hello, Misha!"; // исходная строка
string str1 = "Misha"; // строка, которую надо заменить
string str2 = "Michael"; // строка, на которую надо заменить

sourceString.replace(sourceString.find(str1), str1.length(), str2);

cout << sourceString << endl; // => Hello, Michael!
```

Comment: @Егор отметьте мой ответ, если он вам помог :)

Answer (score 0):

Код:

```
auto replace(const std::string& str, const std::string& from, const std::string& to, unsigned count = std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::max()) -> std::string
{
    std::string res { str };
    std::string::size_type prev_pos { 0 };

    for (auto i = 0U; i < count; ++i)
    {
        if (const auto pos = res.find(from, prev_pos); pos != std::string::npos)
        {
            res.replace(pos, std::size(from), to);
            prev_pos = pos;
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }

    return res;
}
```

Пояснения:

1. Исходная строка не модифицируется, вместо этого мы создаем ее копию и работаем с ней. Такое поведение характерно для `replace` в Python, но я не уверен, что Вы хотели бы делать так же и в C++ (см. пример ниже).
2. По-умолчанию `count` инициализирован максимальным допустимым значением, которое может хранить `unsigned`. Это значит что замена произойдет для *всех* найденных подстрок `str`, которые равны `from`. Соответственно, если Вы укажите конкретное число (*n*), замена произойдет для первых *n* найденных подстрок (или, правильнее, для *k*, где *k* <= *n*, так как *n* подстрок может просто не быть).

Пример с модификацией исходной строки:

```
auto replace(std::string& str, const std::string& from, const std::string& to, unsigned count = std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::max()) -> void
{
    std::string::size_type prev_pos { 0 };

    for (auto i = 0U; i < count; ++i)
    {
        if (const auto pos = str.find(from, prev_pos); pos != std::string::npos)
        {
            str.replace(pos, std::size(from), to);
            prev_pos = pos;
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Так же необходимо учитывать (вышеприведенные примеры этого не отражают), что после очередной замены размер Вашей строки может достигнуть максимального. Тогда, при очередной замене, будет выброшено исключение `std::length_error` - Вы должны его "перехватить" и корректно обработать.